# How to manage label cardinality for elements not found in log text in loki

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I have jobs in my system being logged into files, where each distinct job output is logged into a different file, named after the job's id.

Most of the actions in the system are executed through these jobs so I'm expecting a high number of them.

My first approach was to label the logs using the file name pattern, which works fine but will produce a stream for each job id.

From the Loki [documentation about label fundamentals](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/fundamentals/labels/) I understand I should be striving to minimize the cardinality of the logs being indexed, which leaves me with a problem.

The job id is something I want users to be able to query by,

- either through the label `{job="myjob", job_id="1234"}`
- or through a text search `{job="myjob"} |= "job_id=1234"` (which is the recommended way to avoid high index cardinality).

Given that the job id is derived from the log file's name and not the log text, how should I approach this?

Is it possible to artificially add the job id to all extracted log line texts? if so, is that a good practice?

How is label cardinality effected over time? as in - if a label value exists only for a limited time span (like a job id, which is limited to that job) is this still considered a bad practice?